# How do I remove all property injections in an IContributeComponentModelConstruction in Castle 3.0?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

I ran into an interesting problem today.

Previously, with Castle 2.5.1, we've been able to do something like this:

```
internal class PropertyInjectionContributor : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {

        model.Properties
            .RemoveAll(ps => !ps.Property.HasCustomAttribute<InjectAttribute>() &&
                             !ps.Property.HasCustomAttribute<InjectOptionallyAttribute>());
```

(InjectAttribute and InjectOptionallyAttribute are attributes in the domain of our own application framework, which is based on Castle Windsor.)

The reason why we're doing this removal is because we want to have more control over what (public) properties are being injected or not.

This was possible because in Castle 2.5.1, PropertySetCollection was a Collection, which would gladly accept modifications. :-) (actually, I'm note sure if this was the "pristine" upstream Castle 2.5.1 or my personally modified version, but nevertheless...)

With Castle 3.0, PropertySetCollection is just an IEnumerable which means that it cannot be modified. Now, the ComponentModel has an *Add*Property() method but no *Remove*Property() method, so how on earth do I get this done now??? :-)

Any help is appreciated. We're moving away from having Castle Windsor embedded in "source" format in our project (which meant that we could do small modifications as needed...), towards using the plain DLLs instead (and ILMerging them into our framework). This means that all "solutions" that imply personal patching of the Castle code is simply a no-op.

TIA.

Best regards,
Per

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx, under the "Filtering of property dependencies" category. This will probably work, just haven't had time to test it yet.